# Unable to install LangugeTools extension for LibreOffice

Tags: libreoffice, language-support

I am opening Extension Manager in LibreOffice.

[image]

Then I am trying to add the LanguageTools extensions that I have already downloaded.

[image]

Then I get the error "Could not create Java Implementation loader".

[image]

What should I do now?

Comment: Try to install this package `libreoffice-java-common`, source https://www.languagetool.org/issues/ Check the "Try these suggestions" link.

Comment: @MarkKirby did it but the error persists

Comment: I don't have much else on this, it also says you need JRE8 do you have that version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is outdated java runtime, this plug in requires `JRE8`.

To install `JRE8` run this commands in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre
```

You may also need this package

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice-java-common
```

[Source](https://www.languagetool.org/issues/) and other troubleshooting tips.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `JRE8`

Press

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

The terminal opens

Now type

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo pt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

This install java8 in the system.

To check the version type-

```
java -version
```

which gives you the output

```
java version "1.8.0_91"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)
```

OR

```
javac -version
```

which gives you the output

```
javac 1.8.0_91
```

You may also need to install libreoffice-java-common.

For this type:

```
sudo apt get install libreoffice-java-common
```